# My State Does Change But Components Are Disappear When I Update My State In React Native How To Fıx This?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const DetailedSearchScreen=({ navigation })=> {
  const mydefauthor='no';
  const mydeftitle='data';
  var [dataset, setDataset]=useState({data:[{Author:'Deneme', Title:'yapiyorum'}]});
  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      
      <TextInput onChangeText={text=>det_author=text} placeholder="Enter Author" style={styles.item_style} onClick={()=>{
       console.log(dataset, "You are the hero!");
      }}/>
      <TextInput onChangeText={text=>det_keyword=text} placeholder="Enter Keyword" style={styles.item_style}/>
      <TextInput onChangeText={text=>det_year=parseInt(text)} placeholder="Year" style={styles.item_style}/>
      <TextInput onChangeText={text=>det_sub_date=text} placeholder="Enter Submission Date As Year-Month-Day" style={styles.item_style}/>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
        var data_=make_search();
        console.log("Data info: ",dataset);
        var item={};
        item['data']=data_;
        setDataset(Object.assign({...dataset, ...item}));
        console.log(dataset, "Yine mi olmadı be");
      }} style={styles.button}><Text>Search</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <View>  
          {
          dataset['data'].map((item, key)=>{
            console.log(item);
            return(
              <Text>{item['Author']}</Text>
            );
          })}
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

part of the code is like that, when I read from the console.log result, it shows that state is changed but my mapped components disappear when I updated the state

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enter your key prop in the Text element. You should have

```
<Text key={key}> ... </Text>
```

Also here you are using the array index as a key and it might cause errors.

You should use something that is unique to that data and will not change (title or author if they are unique and immutable).

The best option would be to have a unique id.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I changed my code like this: <View>  
          {
          dataset['data'].map((item, key)=>{
            console.log(item);
            return(
              <Text key={item['Thesis_No']}>{item['Author']}</Text>
            );
          })}
        </View> but it didn't work either

Comment: Are you sure the item['Thesis_No'] is unique and doesn't change? Usually when you have an issue in a map with react, it comes from the key prop.

Comment: If after you've read the docs thoroughly checked the key you can't find it please write a minimal reproductible example of your code so that someone can help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yeah I am sure that thesis no is unique for its data and when get a new data, the other thesis has differint Thesis_No

Comment: Actually I have also tried Object.assign method to merge the objects instead of replacing it with Object.assign({}, dataset, item) but the result is same